# Which crystal do i choose in atmel studio?

Tags: atmega, atmel, crystal, atmel-studio, fuse-bits

I'm trying to use [this 16mhz crystal](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ecs-inc/ECS-160-20-3X-TR/XC1776CT-ND/2676640) with an atmega328 chip and I need to set the fuses for it in atmel studio. But I have no idea which option is the correct choice. None of them say 16mhz.

I've has success in the past but I've bricked chips in the past by choosing the wrong one so I'd appreciate your guidance in making the correct choice.

[image]

Comment: mHz would be milli hertz, mhz is even worse and the goldilocks phrase is MHz I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose "Ext. Full-Swing Crystal". You can choose the one with maximum delay if startup time is not critical for you to stay safe.